# Is there a way to find out whether a method is static or non-static?

Tags: java, methods, javadoc

In java 7 docs, under the section "Method Summary", there are different tabs to filter methods accordingly like *Static Methods*, *Instance Methods*, *Concrete Methods*, *Deprecated Methods*. Previously  this feature was not there.
Is there some other way in which I can find *visually* if a method belongs to one of above categories?

Comment: Use an IDE that flags this information for you.

Comment: These tabs are still available: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html ...

Comment: @Tom Not for version 7

Comment: @MuratK. Then one just need to look if the return type as a "static" in front of it. Isn't that hard either.

Comment: In Java 1.7 Javadoc, they have "static" "abstract" etc. in the "modifier and type" column. Is that not visual enough?

Comment: ... and "deprecated" in the "method and description" column.

Comment: I was watching a video tutorial, so there were tabs in there. So I got little confused. I am little new to this. Thanks, everyone... :)

Comment: Wow, I've been programming with Java for over 15 years, and I never noticed those tabs on the javadoc pages until you pointed them out :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java 8 Javadoc, your tabs return.

In Java 7 Javadoc:

- **Static Methods** have `static methodName` in the first column
- **Instance Methods** do not have `static` in the first column
- **Concrete Methods** do not have `abstract` in the first column
- **Deprecated** have "**deprecated**" among the text of the second column